Stop Visual Studio Xaml Editor showing snippets when I press the Tab button
After a recent update of either Visual Studio 2022 or R#, now when I'm in the xaml editor and I press the tab key, the snippets dialog pops up.
This is new behaviour, and is incredibly annoying. Can I stop it?
I've searched the settings and the kep mappings, and tried various internet searches, but can't find any specific fixes.
When I press the tab key, I expect the editor to insert a tab character into my document.
What actually happens is that I press the tab key, and the code snippets menu will pop up. If I press the tab key again, it vanishes.
Screen shot as requested after pressing Tab
Same thing, but Ctrl K X

do you have copilot installed or any other intellisense ?

Did you check shortcuts for Edit.InsertSnippet under Options?

I have checked the Edit.InsertSnippet under options. This is still set to Ctrl K X as normal. The snippets shown when I press Tab in a xaml file are NOT the same as the snippets shown when I press Ctrl K X.

Pressing Ctrl K X inany xaml file shows me: 'Expansion: Snippets', but pressing 'Tab' shows 'Multiple Snippets' with my CS file snippets displayed.

Looks like what you described is Intellisense  complete Word Suggestions not code snippets.
If you expect the editor to insert a tab character when pressing the tab key, you can use the option to change the IntelliSense completion mode:
Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion or shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Space.

I tried switching from Automatic to Tab-Only, and there is no difference. Another thing I noticed - probably a new question? - is that undo and redo are disabled in the xaml editor. Ctl-Z does nothing, and the menu is grayed out.

Could you show me a screenshot of your issue : when pressing 'Tab' shows 'Multiple Snippets' with my CS file snippets displayed?

By default, Ctrl+K, X invokes code snippets menu in XAML file. Please check if you have set Tab as a shortcut to invoke code snippets to pop up.
Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard, type snipp in Show commands containing
and find Edit.InsertSnippet.
You can assign other keyboards to InsertSnippet.

Besides, this doc XAML code snippets notes

We've enhanced IntelliSense so that it supports showing XAML snippets.

Looks like code snippets is a built-in in IntelliSense. I'm afraid there is no settings/options available to disable it.
